# Haskell collections with guaranteed worst-case bounds for every single operation?

Tags: haskell, collections, amortized-analysis

Such structures are necessary for real-time applications - for example user interfaces. (Users don't care if clicking a button takes 0.1s or 0.2s, but they do care if the 100th click forces an outstanding lazy computation and takes 10s to proceed.)

I was reading Okasaki's thesis [Purely functional data structures](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) and he describes an interesting general method for converting lazy data structures with amortized bounds into structures with the same **worst-case bounds for *every* operation**. The idea is to distribute computations so that at each update some portion of unevaluated thunks is forced.

I wonder, is there any such implementation of standard collections (`Map`, `Set`, etc.) in Haskell?

The [containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.0.0) package says

> The declared cost of each operation is either worst-case or amortized, but remains valid even if structures are shared.

so there is no guarantee for the worst-case bounds for a single operation. There are strict variants like `Data.Map.Strict`, but they're strict in their keys and values:

> Key and value arguments are evaluated to WHNF; Keys and values are evaluated to WHNF before they are stored in the map.

there is nothing about (possible) strictness of its structure.

Comment: Worst case assymptotic bounds for your data structure may or may not translate into real time behavior.  You are working in a garbage collected language, so your cost model only works in the amortized case anyways.  Arbitrary GC pauses are still going to be possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> there is nothing about (possible) strictness of its structure.

Go looking for the source, e.g. for [`Data.Map.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.0.0/doc/html/src/Data-Map-Base.html#Map)

```
-- See Note: Order of constructors
data Map k a  = Bin {-# UNPACK #-} !Size !k a !(Map k a) !(Map k a)
              | Tip
```

You see that a `Map` is totally spine-strict (and strict in the keys, even with `Data.Map.Lazy`), if you evaluate it to WHNF, the complete spine is forced. The same holds for `IntMap`s, `Set`s and `IntSet`s.

So you can prevent the construction of large thunks (except for the mapped-to/contained values) easily by forcing the container to WHNF before every operation. The prevention of large thunks for the contained values [a common cause for time (and space) leaks] is automatic for the `Data.XYZ.Strict` variants (caveat: the values are only evaluated to WHNF, if you need more, you have to do it yourself by e.g. `deepseq`ing any changed values immediatley after the operation), something you need to handle yourself with the `Data.XYZ.Lazy` variants.

Thus

> Users don't care if clicking a button takes 0.1s or 0.2s, but they do care if the 100th click forces an outstanding lazy computation and takes 10s to proceed.

is an easily avoided problem with these containers.

However, it could still be that the 100th click takes *much* longer to process than the average, not due to outstanding lazy computations, but due to the algorithm (consider the classic queue implementation with two lists, the front, where you dequeue elements by `dequeue (Q (x:xs) ys) = (x, Q xs ys)` in O(1), and the back where you `enqueue y (Q xs ys) = Q xs (y:ys)` in O(1), well, except that dequeuing takes O(size) when the front list is empty and the back needs to be reversed first, but it's O(1) amortized still) without changing the amortized cost.

I don't know if the algorithms used in [containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) have any such cases, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Ad queues: That's just what Okasaki is solving. He schedules the reversal at a proper time and then forces a constant part of the reversal at each update so that when the reversed part is needed, it's fully evaluated.